# RHEL service wouldn't start using Puppet

Tags: puppet, rhel, gitlab

I was trying to set up gitlab using this module (https://github.com/sbadia/puppet-gitlab) with some modification to work with RVM and RHEL 6. I got everything working except the gitlab service wouldn't start.

The service is defined as:

```
 service {
    'gitlab':
      ensure     => running,
      pattern    => 'puma',
      hasrestart => true,
      enable     => true,
      hasstatus  => false,
      subscribe  => File['/etc/init.d/gitlab'],
  }
```

The related output from agent with debug enabled:

```
Debug: Service[gitlab](provider=redhat): Executing 'ps -ef'
Debug: Executing '/sbin/chkconfig gitlab'
Debug: Executing '/sbin/service gitlab start'
Debug: Executing '/sbin/chkconfig gitlab'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Gitlab::Server/Service[gitlab]/ensure: ensure changed 'stopped' to 'running'
Debug: /Stage[main]/Gitlab::Server/Service[gitlab]: The container Class[Gitlab::Server] will propagate my refresh even
t
Info: /Stage[main]/Gitlab::Server/Service[gitlab]: Unscheduling refresh on Service[gitlab]
Debug: Class[Gitlab::Server]: The container Stage[main] will propagate my refresh event
Debug: Finishing transaction 70257873749220
```

It seems the /sbin/service gitlab start got executed. But the service is not started (no entries in log either). However, if I manually run service gitlab start, it works fine.

I noticed that there is a line saying "Unscheduling refresh on Service[gitlab]". Not sure why and if it has anything to do with it. Any advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I suspect it comes down to:

You have set `ensure => running` yet provided no status command for puppet to check whether the service is actually running (`hasstatus => false`).

Have a look at this [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=908655#c25) comment for a bit more insight.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, according to puppet manual:
   "If a service’s init script does not support any kind of status command, you should set hasstatus to false and either provide a specific command using the status attribute or expect that Puppet will look for the service name in the process table." Pattern parameter provides "puma" to look for in process table. It should be able to tell if it's running or not, is it?